# CakePHP 3: HasOne relation throws SQLSTATE[23000]: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've got a strange issue with CakePHP which I can't resolve after 2 hours of debugging.

I got the following tables (shortened):

```
Messages
- id        - char(36)
- type      - varchar
- type_id   - char(36)

Texts
- id        - char(36)
- body      - text
```

Messages has an HasOne relation with Texts (where `type` should be `TEXT`), and Texts has a BelongsTo relation with Messages.

My Tables look like:

```
// MessagesTable
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('messages');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasOne('Texts', [
        'bindingKey' => 'type_id',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
    ]);

}

// TextsTable
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('texts');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Messages', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'bindingKey' => 'type_id'
    ]);
}
```

When I try to create a message with an associated text the data will look like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "TEXT",
        "text": {
            "body": "Hey there! This is a manual API request!"
        }
    }
}
```

I will get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null
```

[image]

A markable breakthrough is; when I remove `'bindingKey' => 'type_id',` on the Tables, the rows are added to the database, while there is no link (the `type_id` column on `messages` is empty).

What am I doing wrong? I've read through http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations a lot, and my code looks right...

Thank you very much :)

#### EDIT

I have a dirty fix for now... It looks like the `id` from the `texts` will not be generated because it keeps looking at `messages`... So I added the following to my controller:

```
$entity->set('type_id', Text::uuid());
```

This code generates an `uuid` for the `type_id` column.

And guess what... The `id` column from `texts` has been filled with THAT value!

My conclusion: the `bindingKey` forces the 'child' to look at the 'parent' for the id which should not be done in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined primary key as char , does that auto increment ?
Or have you managed that id for char to be auto increment and can cakephp handle such cases for making relations between table ? If it can , I would be happy for knowing such things. But if it can't that primary key should be integer as:

```
    Messages
  - id        - integer(11)
  - type      - varchar
  - type_id   - integer(11)

   Texts
  - id        - integer(11)
  - body      - text
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using `char(36)` without auto incremention because CakePHP will automatically add uuid's. This works generally, but not in case of those relations I demonstrated